# Conditional based copy cells to another sheet cancelled

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to write macro to copy cells (condition based) from one sheet to another sheet.
When I am running the macro, I got "pasteSpecial method of Range class failed" error.

I tried to solve it. But I could not able to do it.

```
 Sub update_tuning()
Dim tun_num, tun_select, source1, target1 As Range
Dim r, lr As Long


Sheets("Calc").Select
Set tun_num = Range("B2")

If tun_num <> Null Then
Sheets("Calc").Select
Range("C22:BE22").Select
Selection.Copy

End If

Sheets("DATA_Lbf_ft").Select
lr = Sheets("DATA_Lbf_ft").Range("B3:B1803").Count

For r = 3 To lr
 If Range("B" & r).Value = tun_num Then
 Exit For
 End If
 Next r

Sheets("DATA_Lbf_ft").Range("B" & r).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

 End Sub
```

Please give your comments to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many operations between your `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial`. The `.CutCopyMode` (when you would normally see the blinking border around the copied cell(s) on the worksheet) is cancelled by the other operations.

It would be better to copy and paste after you have made the destination determination.

```
For r = 3 To lr
  If Range("B" & r).Value = tun_num Then
    Exit For
  End If
Next r

Sheets("Calc").Range("C22:BE22").copy _
  destination:=Sheets("DATA_Lbf_ft").Range("B" & r)
```

If you abandon the original copy operation and use this method, I believe you should get the results you are looking for.

**Addendum:**

For value only transfer substitute the following for the `.Copy Destination:= ...` operation.

```
  With Sheets("Calc").Range("C22:BE22")
      Sheets("DATA_Lbf_ft").Range("B" & r).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Cells.Value
  End With
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped, It makes sense and I didn't think of that. After modifying the macro as like you told, I can able to run it without error. But cells are copied with formulae.  I want to copy only values to the next sheet. Can you please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: @jsmanian - I prefer the direct value transfer method instead of *Copy, Paste Special, Value*. The only disadvantage is that target range receiving the values must be the same size as the source range so it takes a few extra lines to make sure of that through `.Resize`.,